# Why does my view move when I set its frame after changing its anchorPoint?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit

I made two instances of `UILabel` and added them to my `ViewController`'s view.
And then I changed the `anchorPoint` of each from 0.5 to 1.0 (x and y).

Next, I reset the frame of `uiLabel2` to its frame I created it with: (100,100,100,20).

When I run the app, `uiLabel1` and `uiLabel2` show at different positions.  Why?

```
UILabel *uiLabel1 = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 20)] autorelease];
uiLabel1.text = @"UILabel1";
uiLabel1.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1, 1);

UILabel *uiLabel2 = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 20)] autorelease];
uiLabel2.text = @"UILabel2";
uiLabel2.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1, 1);
uiLabel2.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 20);

[self.view addSubview:uiLabel1];
[self.view addSubview:uiLabel2];
```

[image]

Answer (score 48, accepted):

A `CALayer` has four properties that determine where it appears in its superlayer:

- `position` (which is the same as the view's `center` property)
- `bounds` (actually only the `size` part of `bounds`)
- `anchorPoint`
- `transform`

You will notice that `frame` is **not** one of those properties.  The `frame` property is actually derived from those properties.  When you set the `frame` property, the layer actually changes its `center` and `bounds.size` based on the frame you provide and the layer's existing `anchorPoint`.

You create the first layer (by creating the first `UILabel`, which is a subclass of `UIView`, and every `UIView` has a layer), giving it a frame of 100,100,100,20.  The layer has a default anchor point of 0.5,0.5.  So it computes its bounds as 0,0,100,20 and its position as 150,110.  It looks like this:

[image: anchor at center]

Then you change its anchor point to 1,1.  Since you don't change the layer's position or bounds directly, and you don't change them indirectly by setting its frame, the layer moves so that its new anchor point is at its (unchanged) position in its superlayer:

[image: anchor at corner]

If you ask for the layer's (or view's) frame now, you will get 50,90,100,20.

When you create the second layer (for the second `UILabel`), after changing its anchor point, you set its frame.  So the layer computes a new position and bounds based on the frame you provide and its existing anchor point:

[image: anchor at corner with reset frame]

If you ask the layer (or view) for its frame now, you will get the frame you set, 100,100,100,20.  But if you ask for its position (or the view's center), you will get 200,120.

Comment: Oh! rob!. Thank you for your great and detail answer.

Comment: and what about transform? still trying to apply scale animation on a layer with anchorPoint(0.5, 0.5) and it remain scaling from top left corner, like it's anchorPoint(0.0, 0.0)

Comment: Please post your own question with code and screen shots.

Answer (score 4):

Well that is exactly what an anchor point does. Before changing the anchor points, you were setting the frame based of the center of the label. After that, you are setting the frame based on the right bottom corner.

Since you were only resetting the frame for just one label, one adjusted its frame based on the new anchor point and the other one stayed at the old position.

If you want them to be at the same point, then you need to reset the frame for both of them after editing the anchor point, OR don't the anchor point at all.

[This guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CoreAnimationBasics/CoreAnimationBasics.html) explains more about anchor points.