# Animate a UIImageView from center of the UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiviewanimation

I have a `UIImageView` that should animate from `size (0,0) --> (93,75)`

I have the following

```
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                 animations:^{
                     imgButton.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(imgButton.bounds.size.width/2, imgButton.bounds.size.height/2);
                     CGRect btnFrame = imgButton.frame;
                     btnFrame.size.width = 105;
                     btnFrame.size.height = 85;
                     imgButton.frame = btnFrame;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [self animageButton2:imgButton];
                 }];
```

This is working but the only problem I have is that it is not animating from the center of the `UIImageView` but from the top left corner.

Anybody got a clue?

Comment: Did you actually read the documentation on `anchorPoint`?  I guess no because you are not giving it the correct value.  Furthermore, it only applies to `CGAffineTransform` manipulations, not size.  If you want to do it this way you will have to adjust the origin yourself.  I suggest setting the scale to zero and animating it up to 1.

Answer (score 4):

I've solved it with the help of Borrden. This is what my solution was.

First create an imageview

```
UIImageView *imgLineup = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, y, 93, 75)];
imgLineup.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.0, 0.0);
```

And then to the following.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         imgButton.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
                         imgButton.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.0, 1.0);

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        NSLog(@"done");
                     }];
```

Comment: Default value of `anchorPoint` is `(0.5,0.5)` hence reassigning it is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

just try with this. import `#import  <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` then put below code while adding the uimageView into subView of self.view

```
CABasicAnimation *zoomAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
[zoomAnimation setDuration:0.8];
[zoomAnimation setRepeatCount:1];
[zoomAnimation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.1]];
[zoomAnimation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]];
[zoomAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
[[imageView layer] addAnimation:zoomAnimation forKey:@"zoom"];
```

Comment: hello. I want to add some action at end of animation, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

What i suggest may be kind of hack but it will be an easier way to achieve what you want:

- You set the initial frame of imageView as:

  ```
  CGRectMake(center, center, 0, 0);
  ```

  So in your case it will be something closer to :

  ```
  CGRectMake(46, 37, 0, 0);
  ```
- Then animate it with new rect of something like this:

  ```
  CGRectMake(0, 0,93,75);
  ```

  You can use simple UIViewAnimation for this;

  ```
      [UIView beginAnimations:@"zoom" context:NULL];
       [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
      imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 93, 75); ;
      [UIView commitAnimations];
  ```

Hope It works

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is a scale transform i.e. animating UIView size from size(0,0) to size(w,h). Same effect can be achieved by `CGAffineTransformMakeScale`.

Initially when you create the view apply `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.0,0.0)` then animate size scale up to `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0,1.0)`.

Code:

```
// Create the view and apply correct frame
UIView *tagView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 100, 100)];
tagView.tag = kTag;
//Apply scale transform, to make size(0,0) 
tagView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0,0);
[self.view addSubview:tagView];

/// ............

UIView *tagView = [self.view viewWithTag:kTag];
//Now animate the view size scale up
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
        delay:0
        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
        animations:^{
                        tagView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0,1.0);
                    }
        completion:NULL
 ];
```

This animation will happen about the center point of the view as you want, thus avoiding the need to play with `anchorPoint` and `frame`, which can be tricky. Read more about the relation between `frame` and `anchorPoint` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12208587/1407017).